# Trigger a mouse event to slide a android viewpager when all fragments in List<Fragment>

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, mouseevent, fragmentpageradapter

How can I slide a viewpager if I use `ListFragment>` with FragmentPagerAdapter. I don't use Fragment Manager. I think the best way to do that is if I can trigger a mouse event on button click to slide from one fragment to another, is this possible in android? I didn't find the material on the web about this subject, what I found is how to listen the mouse events.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I didn't need any mouse Trigger event. There is an ViewPager method that solved me the problem.

```
setCurrentItem(int item, boolean smoothScroll)
```